# Mule ESB: How to use xpath expression on session variable?

Tags: xpath, mule

I have a requirement to extract some information form session variables. The session variables Type is String and contains XML. i tried XPATH expression like -

```
xpath('//tns:CreateUpdateRQ/tns:RequestInfo/sns:requestSourceID',sessionVars.originalMessage)
```

however I get exception stating "Could not find transformer NULL Payload to Document". I tried MEL like - `#[sessionVars.originalMessage.CreateUpdateRQ.RequestInfo.requestID]`. But it's not working either.

How can I extract information from session variable of Type string holding XML.

P.S. I can set the payload to sesion variable & use xpath but it's not suitable for my case because I need to extract the information from session variable 7 pass it as argument to datamapper.

Appreciate you help on this.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate reading the xml file, I recommend transforming String (Object) to xml, for example:

```
<xml:object-to-xml-transformer />
```

then

```
<logger level="WARN" message="#[xpath://soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body//...]" />
```

In short, make sure the payload is XML type, you can by setting it

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I am looking to extract information from session variable (which stores a XML String). I have tried multiple options like -"#[xpath('//tns:CreateUpdateSchoolRQ/tns:requestInfo',sessionVars.originalSchoolMessage)]" & .text, .getText() etc. but non are working. if  I set the session variable as payload & use the xpath, i get proper result. But i want to directly extract information from the session variable.